# Tu Bishvat Esrog

Tags: tu-bishvat, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, tefilla

Why do people Pray for a Esrog on Tubishvat what the source and what is the connection between Tubishvat between them?

Comment: I have never heard of that practice. Where have you read about or seen it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.613.org/noam/tubeshvat.htm

has a source from the Ben Ish Chai and the Bnei Yissachar with Tefilos

Comment: The Bnei Yissachar is quoted in Taamei Haminhagim 866: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=383

Answer (score 4):

I believe it may appear in the Netiei Gavriel?

Anways, some say that on Tu B'shvat, you should pray for a good esrog, some 7--8 months from now.

The reason is straightforward enough, as I understand it: Tu B'shvat is the new year (Rosh Hashanah) for fruit trees, so you pray now that the fruit tree that will produce your mitzva fruit (i.e. esrog) later this year will do so well.

Comment: Your answer just made me wonder - what exactly would the נוסח of such a תפילה be? Are you yourself the subject? Is it the אתרוג? The tree? Do you invoke the first פרק of תהילים?